# start text and number from the same position

Tags: javascript, css

I want to start the two span from the same position. The two span includes two number also.

I have tried below codes. But When the number digit increase, It changed the position.

```
<div>
    <p style={{ float: 'left' }}>
        pointA
        <span>{number}</span>
        End<br/>
        <span>pointB<span>
         {number}
        </span>End<br/></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

It output is like this ->

```
pointA  0 End
pointB 123 End
```

But I want a output like this->

```
pointA  0    End
pointB  123  End
```

Comment: Maybe use something more semantically correct tags than a `<p>` :)

Comment: Either use a better layout where you can control widths or padd the shorter number with non breaking spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way could be to use tables.

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>pointA</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>End</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>pointB</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>End</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Another solution could be:

```css
.container {
    width: 200px;
}


.row {
    width: 100%;
    display: table
}

.col {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 33.3%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">pointA</div>
        <div class="col">0</div>
        <div class="col">End</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">pointB</div>
        <div class="col">123</div>
        <div class="col">End</div>
    </div>
</div>
```